# ILC circuit second order equation

Tags: circuit-analysis, passive-networks

Consider this circuit.

[image: ILC circuit]

The question asks for write an algebraic expression for the second derivative of the inductor current in terms of the source current \$I\$, the inductor current \$iL\$, the inductance \$L\$, and the capacitance \$ C\$.

\$\frac{d^2i_L}{dt^2}=?\$

So far so good. But let's look answer.

[image: answer]

How should capacitor current be equal to inductor voltage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a typo.  What was probably meant was \$v_c = v_L\$.
From this, we can say that \$v_c = Li_L^\prime\$, which in turn implies \$i_c = CLi_L^{\prime\prime}\$.

Comment: As far as I understand calculation steps are as follows.

1 - \$ \large \frac {1}{C} \int_{-\infty}^t i_C \,dt= L \frac{di_L}{dt} \$

2- \$ \large \int_{-\infty}^t i_C \,dt= CL \frac{di_L}{dt} \$ and differentiate both sides which gives

3- \$ \large i_C= CL \frac{d^2{i_L}}{dt^2} \$